# How do I change the rendering speed in the Project Monitor?

Tags: lag, frame-rate, ubuntu-20.04, video-editing

I have just installed Kdenlive on Ubuntu 20.04 and I am following the [quickstart manual](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/QuickStart), and it's all fine except for one thing: Whenever I try to preview the video in the Project Monitor, it stutters very badly.

When I preview a clip in the Clip Monitor, it plays smoothly, incrementing the frames one by one, but when I preview the video in the Project Monitor, it skips the timeline cursor by a second instead incrementing the frames.

[Here's a video of what's happening.](https://gofile.io/d/ItIF6G)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've found the problem, it was a problem with my GPU drivers, as I had a Nvidia GPU but it wasn't being detected. Today I refreshed and upgraded the packages and solved some secure boot issue and Kdenlive is working fine now.